# How to set EditText's height to maximum minus other buttons' and EditText's heights?

Tags: android, android-layout, height

I would like to fill the screen with my `EditText` View which would have all the screen height minus the height of buttons and `EditText`s in this `Activity`

My activity's xml

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_pickcontact_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pickcontact_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="pickContact"
            android:text="@string/pickcontact_string" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_chosen_contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chosen_contact"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/contact_default_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chosen_contact_tel_number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/contact_default_number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="sendEmail"
            android:text="@string/send_email_btn" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: can you post a screen shot that you want to design?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_pickcontact_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <!-- Blah blah-->
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_chosen_contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <!-- Blah blah-->
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            <!-- android:layout_weight="1" YOU DON'T NEED THAT-->
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <!-- Blah blah-->
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The point is, make the width and height parent layout of the EditText be fill_parent.

Doing this will make all elements after that invisible since the layout has 'filled' the parent, so you should also set a weight for those elements to make sure they are still visible.

While you need to find a proper weight when doing so, making those elements before that would be easier (but you need to change your design then).

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_pickcontact_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pickcontact_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="pickContact"
            android:text="@string/pickcontact_string" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_chosen_contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chosen_contact"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/contact_default_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chosen_contact_tel_number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/contact_default_number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="edit_message"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="sendEmail"
            android:text="@string/send_email_btn" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I gave rest of screen hight to this row "tableRow_message"